# Kibana Server not allowing remote access

Tags: kibana

I've edited my Kibana.yaml config file to allow remote access using the DHCP IP address on my router from a bridged connection using my adapter.

It seems to not establish a connection using the port and IP assigned.

```
    [root@localhost bin]# ./kibana --allow-root
^C^C  log   [14:36:15.000] [info][plugins-service] Plugin "visTypeXy" is disabled.
  log   [14:36:15.025] [info][plugins-service] Plugin "auditTrail" is disabled.
  log   [14:36:15.084] [warning][config][deprecation] Config key [monitoring.cluster_alerts.email_notifications.email_address] will be required for email notifications to work in 8.0."
^C[root@localhost bin]# ./kibana --allow-root &
[1] 2499
[root@localhost bin]#   log   [14:36:23.872] [info][plugins-service] Plugin "visTypeXy" is disabled.
  log   [14:36:23.878] [info][plugins-service] Plugin "auditTrail" is disabled.
  log   [14:36:23.960] [warning][config][deprecation] Config key [monitoring.cluster_alerts.email_notifications.email_address] will be required for email notifications to work in 8.0."
  log   [14:36:24.133] [info][plugins-system] Setting up [96] plugins: [taskManager,licensing,globalSearch,globalSearchProviders,code,usageCollection,xpackLegacy,telemetryCollectionManager,telemetry,telemetryCollectionXpack,kibanaUsageCollection,securityOss,newsfeed,mapsLegacy,kibanaLegacy,translations,share,legacyExport,embeddable,uiActionsEnhanced,expressions,data,home,observability,cloud,console,consoleExtensions,apmOss,searchprofiler,painlessLab,grokdebugger,management,indexPatternManagement,advancedSettings,fileUpload,savedObjects,dashboard,visualizations,visTypeVega,visTypeTimelion,timelion,features,upgradeAssistant,security,snapshotRestore,enterpriseSearch,encryptedSavedObjects,ingestManager,indexManagement,remoteClusters,crossClusterReplication,indexLifecycleManagement,dashboardMode,beatsManagement,transform,ingestPipelines,maps,licenseManagement,graph,dataEnhanced,visTypeTable,visTypeMarkdown,tileMap,regionMap,inputControlVis,visualize,esUiShared,charts,lens,visTypeVislib,visTypeTimeseries,rollup,visTypeTagcloud,visTypeMetric,watcher,discover,discoverEnhanced,savedObjectsManagement,spaces,reporting,lists,eventLog,actions,case,alerts,stackAlerts,triggersActionsUi,ml,securitySolution,infra,monitoring,logstash,apm,uptime,bfetch,canvas]
  log   [14:36:24.394] [warning][config][plugins][security] Generating a random key for xpack.security.encryptionKey. To prevent sessions from being invalidated on restart, please set xpack.security.encryptionKey in kibana.yml
  log   [14:36:24.395] [warning][config][plugins][security] Session cookies will be transmitted over insecure connections. This is not recommended.
  log   [14:36:24.433] [warning][config][encryptedSavedObjects][plugins] Generating a random key for xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey. To be able to decrypt encrypted saved objects attributes after restart, please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in kibana.yml
  log   [14:36:24.439] [warning][ingestManager][plugins] Fleet APIs are disabled due to the Encrypted Saved Objects plugin using an ephemeral encryption key. Please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in kibana.yml.
  log   [14:36:24.561] [warning][config][plugins][reporting] Generating a random key for xpack.reporting.encryptionKey. To prevent sessions from being invalidated on restart, please set xpack.reporting.encryptionKey in kibana.yml
  log   [14:36:24.563] [warning][config][plugins][reporting] Chromium sandbox provides an additional layer of protection, but is not supported for Linux CentOS 8.3.2011
 OS. Automatically setting 'xpack.reporting.capture.browser.chromium.disableSandbox: true'.
  log   [14:36:24.575] [warning][actions][actions][plugins] APIs are disabled due to the Encrypted Saved Objects plugin using an ephemeral encryption key. Please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in kibana.yml.
  log   [14:36:24.596] [warning][alerting][alerts][plugins][plugins] APIs are disabled due to the Encrypted Saved Objects plugin using an ephemeral encryption key. Please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in kibana.yml.
  log   [14:36:24.785] [info][monitoring][monitoring][plugins] config sourced from: production cluster
  log   [14:36:25.067] [info][savedobjects-service] Waiting until all Elasticsearch nodes are compatible with Kibana before starting saved objects migrations...
  log   [14:36:25.409] [info][savedobjects-service] Starting saved objects migrations
  log   [14:36:25.976] [info][plugins-system] Starting [96] plugins: [taskManager,licensing,globalSearch,globalSearchProviders,code,usageCollection,xpackLegacy,telemetryCollectionManager,telemetry,telemetryCollectionXpack,kibanaUsageCollection,securityOss,newsfeed,mapsLegacy,kibanaLegacy,translations,share,legacyExport,embeddable,uiActionsEnhanced,expressions,data,home,observability,cloud,console,consoleExtensions,apmOss,searchprofiler,painlessLab,grokdebugger,management,indexPatternManagement,advancedSettings,fileUpload,savedObjects,dashboard,visualizations,visTypeVega,visTypeTimelion,timelion,features,upgradeAssistant,security,snapshotRestore,enterpriseSearch,encryptedSavedObjects,ingestManager,indexManagement,remoteClusters,crossClusterReplication,indexLifecycleManagement,dashboardMode,beatsManagement,transform,ingestPipelines,maps,licenseManagement,graph,dataEnhanced,visTypeTable,visTypeMarkdown,tileMap,regionMap,inputControlVis,visualize,esUiShared,charts,lens,visTypeVislib,visTypeTimeseries,rollup,visTypeTagcloud,visTypeMetric,watcher,discover,discoverEnhanced,savedObjectsManagement,spaces,reporting,lists,eventLog,actions,case,alerts,stackAlerts,triggersActionsUi,ml,securitySolution,infra,monitoring,logstash,apm,uptime,bfetch,canvas]
  log   [14:36:25.978] [info][plugins][taskManager][taskManager] TaskManager is identified by the Kibana UUID: dbda794a-41a8-4223-b66f-b4fed95353db
  log   [14:36:26.302] [info][crossClusterReplication][plugins] Your basic license does not support crossClusterReplication. Please upgrade your license.
  log   [14:36:26.339] [info][plugins][watcher] Your basic license does not support watcher. Please upgrade your license.
  log   [14:36:26.340] [info][kibana-monitoring][monitoring][monitoring][plugins] Starting monitoring stats collection
[2021-01-16T09:36:26,422][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetadataIndexTemplateService] [localhost.localdomain] adding template [.management-beats] for index patterns [.management-beats]
  log   [14:36:27.290] [info][listening] Server running at http://10.0.0.137:5601
  log   [14:36:28.153] [info][server][Kibana][http] http server running at http://10.0.0.137:5601
  log   [14:36:28.157] [error][data][elasticsearch] [version_conflict_engine_exception]: [task:Actions-actions_telemetry]: version conflict, document already exists (current version [4])
  log   [14:36:28.181] [error][data][elasticsearch] [version_conflict_engine_exception]: [task:Lens-lens_telemetry]: version conflict, document already exists (current version [4])
  log   [14:36:28.182] [error][data][elasticsearch] [version_conflict_engine_exception]: [task:Alerting-alerting_telemetry]: version conflict, document already exists (current version [4])
  log   [14:36:28.183] [error][data][elasticsearch] [version_conflict_engine_exception]: [task:endpoint:user-artifact-packager:1.0.0]: version conflict, document already exists (current version [64])
  log   [14:36:28.184] [error][data][elasticsearch] [version_conflict_engine_exception]: [task:apm-telemetry-task]: version conflict, document already exists (current version [4])
  log   [14:36:28.973] [warning][plugins][reporting] Enabling the Chromium sandbox provides an additional layer of protection.
```

Comment: The logs states `http server running at http://10.0.0.137:5601` so it must be accessible.

Comment: From what I've observed it seems to reject the connection. I've done some troubleshooting using another OS (Ubuntu 20.04.01) and similar results occurred when locally accessing the tool as well. I presume somewhere it's not properly implemented and further troubleshooting is needed.

Comment: If you can share the error you get when you try to connect, it would be helpful

Comment: I've done some digging and discovered my VMhost didn't have sufficient resources. I'm now using a Dell PowerEdge box which is running on SecurityOnion OSI image.